# Ruby protect outer variable inside block

Tags: ruby, block

Lets say have method:

```
def in_block
  x = "This variables outer block"
  3.times do |i|
    x = i
    puts "x inside block - #{x}"
  end
  puts x
end
in_block

# >> x inside block - 0
# >> x inside block - 1
# >> x inside block - 2
# >> 2
```

How i can protect my `x` variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate parameter in block by semicolon `;` this indicates that the block need its own `x`, unrelated to any `x` that have been created already in outside the block.

```
def in_block
  x = "This variables outer block"
  3.times do |i; x|
    x = i
    puts "x inside block - #{x}"
  end
  puts x
end
in_block

# >> x inside block - 0
# >> x inside block - 1
# >> x inside block - 2
# >> This variables outer block
```

But how about simple `,`? it is not the same. Look example that block takes two parameters:

```
def in_block
  #x = "This variables outer block"
  [1,2,3,4].each_with_index do |i; x|
  puts x.class
    x = i
    puts "x inside block - #{x}"
  end
  #puts x
end

in_block # => [1, 2, 3, 4]

# >> NilClass
# >> x inside block - 1
# >> NilClass
# >> x inside block - 2
# >> NilClass
# >> x inside block - 3
# >> NilClass
# >> x inside block - 4
```

and with `,`:

```
def in_block
  #x = "This variables outer block"
  [1,2,3,4].each_with_index do |i, x|
  puts x.class
    x = i
    puts "x inside block - #{x}"
  end
  #puts x
end

in_block # => [1, 2, 3, 4]

# >> Fixnum
# >> x inside block - 1
# >> Fixnum
# >> x inside block - 2
# >> Fixnum
# >> x inside block - 3
# >> Fixnum
# >> x inside block - 4
```